# How to shorten this pyramid shaped javascript?

Tags: javascript, http, web-applications, callback

I'm trying to develop a quiz application.

I'm doing asynchronous requests to a server to get the questions, and then send back the answer with POST.

This continues until there are no questions left.

I know my code is a bad solution, but I couldn't come up with a better way of doing it. Any suggestions?

My code:

```
  quizStart(input, config) {
    var ajaxConfig;
    var query;
    var inputValue;
    var answerButton = document.querySelector("#answer .button");

    input.startGame.addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.totalTime.start();
        this.timer.countdown(20);

        input.startText.parentNode.removeChild(input.startText);

        ajaxConfig = {
            method: "GET",
            contentType: "application/JSON",
            url: config.url,
            query: null
        };

        ajax.request(ajaxConfig).then(function(data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            this.altsOrIn(data);
            answerButton = document.querySelector("#answer .button");
            inputValue = input.answer.querySelector("#valueInput");

            answerButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
                if (inputValue.value === "") { return;}
                this.timer.stop();

                query = {
                    answer: inputValue.value
                };

                ajaxConfig = {
                    method: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/JSON",
                    url: data.nextURL,
                    query: JSON.stringify(query)
                };

                ajax.request(ajaxConfig).then(function(data) {
                    data = JSON.parse(data);
                    this.result(data);

                    answerButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
                        this.timer.countdown(20);

                        ajaxConfig = {
                            method: "GET",
                            contentType: "application/JSON",
                            url: data.nextURL,
                            query: null
                        };
```

Comment: Please elaborate what you really want to achieve...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have single function to make Ajax request like below

```
function ajaxGETHandler(url) {

 ajaxConfig = {
            method: "GET",
            contentType: "application/JSON",
            url: url,
            query: null
        };

$.ajax(ajaxConfig).success(successGetHandler);
}

function ajaxPostHandler(url,data){
     ajaxConfig = {
            method: "POST",
            contentType: "application/JSON",
            url: url,
            query: null
        };

$.ajax(ajaxConfig).success(successPostHandler);
}
```

then define your sucessGetHandler and successPostHandler

```
function successGetHandler(response) {
  //do stuff here with response
}

function successPostHandler(response) {
 //do stuff here with response
}
```

and define a function for the click event

```
function btnClickHandler(e) {

        this.totalTime.start();
        this.timer.countdown(20);

 //call ajaxgethandler and ajaxpost handler here
}

btn.addEventListener("click",btnClickHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can define named functions instead of declaring them in the `then` clause.

For example:

```
var gameStart = function() { 
  // … 
  answerButton.addEventListener("click", firstStep);
};

var firstStep = function() { … };


input.startGame.addEventListener("click", gameStart);
```